# Wasserstein metric: conditions for the existence of minimizer and duality

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, optimal-transport

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $\mathcal P(X)$ be the set of all Borel probability measures on $(X,d)$. The Wasserstein distance on $\mathcal P(X)$ is given by
$$
  W_d(\mu,\bar\mu):=\inf_{M\in C(\mu,\bar\mu)}\int\limits_{X\times X} d(x,y)M(dx\times dy)
$$
where $C(\mu,\bar\mu)$ is a set of all measures $M$ whose marginals are $\mu$ and $\bar \mu$. A very much related is the Kantorovich distance on $\mathcal P(X)$ given by
$$
  K_d(\mu,\bar\mu) :=  \sup\left\{\int_X f(x)(\mu-\bar\mu)(dx): f\in N(X,d) \right\}
$$
where $N(X,d)$ is a set of all real-valued non-expansive maps (i.e. whose Lipschitz constant is $1$).

I wonder about the conditions on $(X,d)$ that are sufficient for the following:

1. The minimizer for the Wasserstein distance exists. That is, for any $\mu,\bar\mu \in \mathcal P(X)$ there exists $M^*\in C(\mu,\bar\mu)$ such that
   $$
     W_d(\mu,\bar\mu):=\int\limits_{X\times X} d(x,y)M^*(dx\times dy).
   $$
2. The duality holds, that is $W_d = K_d$.

I would be interested in seeing precise references as well. As far as I remember, both features are true for compact spaces, but I also wondered about Polish space and Borel spaces (Borel subsets of Polish spaces).

Answer (score 4):

For Polish $X$:

- Optimal measure $M^*$ exists: *Topics in Optimal Transportation* (Theorem 1.3 on page 19) and *Optimal Transport* (Theorem 4.1 on page 32)
- Equality $K_d=W_d$ holds: *Topics in Optimal Transportation* (Theorem 1.14 on page 34) and *Optimal Transport* (Remark 6.5 on page 95).

The first of two books is more  analysis-oriented, and may be easier to read. The second one is available for download on [Villani's page](http://cedricvillani.org/for-mathematicians/complete-list-of-publications/#books).

I have not seen any studies of this in incomplete spaces. It seems one could pass to completion $\overline{X}$, apply the result, and observe that the optimal measure gives full mass to $X\times X$, because its marginals give full mass to $X$.

Comment: Thanks - the idea regarding the completion is clear. What about the duality in such case?

Comment: @Ilya I think duality works too. The point being, after completion we still have the same set of 1-Lipschitz functions, and integration takes place on $X$ only since this is where the measure is.